# MSSQL - Check where no other value exists

Tags: sql-server

Relatively simple one (I think) but I'm not too sure on how to do it.

I have a set of data and I want to return the IDs where the Result was **only** Bad, e.g. in the below set, only 100 should be returned. 200 should be excluded as it had a result of 'Good'.

```
    UID ID  Date/Time           Result
    1   100 02/04/2014 08:00    Bad
    2   200 02/04/2014 08:05    Bad
    3   100 03/04/2014 08:10    Bad
    4   100 03/04/2014 08:20    Bad
    5   200 03/04/2014 09:00    Bad
    6   200 03/04/2014 18:00    Good
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE1
WHERE RESULT = 'BAD' AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM WHERE RESULT = 'GOOD')
```

Comment: Can't you just use RESULT = 'BAD'? No need for IN.

Answer (score 1):

Translating your title: use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
   WHERE t.ID = t2.ID AND t2.Result = 'Good'
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d523a/1/0)</kbd>

or `ALL`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE 'Bad' = ALL(
   SELECT t2.Result FROM dbo.TableName t2
   WHERE t.ID = t2.ID 
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d523a/4/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the *complete* rows, and not just the `ID`s, you can use a couple of windowed aggregates:

```
declare @t table (UID int,ID int,dt datetime,Result varchar(19))
insert into @t(UID,ID,dt,Result) values
(1,100,'2014-04-02T08:00:00','Bad'),
(2,200,'2014-04-02T08:05:00','Bad'),
(3,100,'2014-04-03T08:10:00','Bad'),
(4,100,'2014-04-03T08:20:00','Bad'),
(5,200,'2014-04-03T09:00:00','Bad'),
(6,200,'2014-04-03T18:00:00','Good')

;With MinMax as (
    select *,
        MIN(Result) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as minR,
        MAX(Result) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as maxR
    from @t
)
select UID,ID,dt,Result from MinMax
where minR = maxR and minR = 'Bad'
```

Because when the minimum and maximum values for a particular row are equal, you know that *all* of the observed values were equal.

Result:

```
UID         ID          dt                      Result
----------- ----------- ----------------------- -------------------
3           100         2014-04-03 08:10:00.000 Bad
4           100         2014-04-03 08:20:00.000 Bad
1           100         2014-04-02 08:00:00.000 Bad
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the distinct value of ID not associated with a good result?
Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM   myTable
WHERE  ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM myTable WHERE Result = 'Good')
```

should do the trick.

If all the data of the "bad" ID is needed then

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable
WHERE  ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM myTable WHERE Result = 'Good')
```